# Reversing an SVG Path

Tags: html, animation, svg, path, adobe-illustrator

Is there a simple method for reversing an SVG path?  How can I make this start at the top left, rather than the bottom right?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="548.9px" height="620px" viewBox="0 0 548.9 620" xml:space="preserve">
    <path d="M305.3,461.7c-13.6,2.2-66,1.3-99.6-21.9c-77.4-53.3-42.5-147.1-95.4-204.1c-42.2-45.6-98-59.2-60-131.7"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: transform="scale(-1,-1)" perhaps. You'll need a translae too though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org):

1. Open this svg file in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org).
2. select the path
3. click Menu -> Path -> Reverse
4. save the file or open the xml editor in Inkscape to find the new path data.

Or use javascript. get and reverse each path segment.

Comment: almost the same in Sketch )

Comment: in order to open the XML editor click on Edit > XML Editor

Answer (score 12):

You can use [svgpathtools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svgpathtools/).

```
from svgpathtools import parse_path
path = parse_path("M305.3,461.7c-13.6,2.2-66,1.3-99.6-21.9c-77.4-53.3-42.5-147.1-95.4-204.1c-42.2-45.6-98-59.2-60-131.7")

print(path.reversed().d())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Figma, you can paste the SVG as "vector", then right-click and choose "Flip Horintally" or "Flip Vertically" (can be both).